# bind an Array FormBuilder to template

Tags: typescript, angular

i'm having trouble representing my Formbuilder Array on my template:

```
this.form = fb.group({
    label: [],
    actionType: [],
    description: [],
    HTTPMethod: [],
    resourcePattern: [],
    status: [],
    parameters: fb.array([     // =====> that's what i want to represent
        fb.group({
            Parameter: fb.group({
                label: [],
                description: [],
                mandatory: [],
                parameterType: [],
                dataType: [],
                requestType: [],
                processParameterIdentifier: []
            })
        })
    ])
});
```

I'm representing it like this on my Template:

```
<fieldset ngControlGroup="parameters">
    <div ngControlGroup="">
        <div *ngIf = "filtred" class="form-group" ngControlGroup="Parameter">
            <!--  <label>Paramètres</label> -->
            <div class="form-group" *ngFor="#parametre of processListe?.Process?.parameters, #i = index">
                <h2>Action Parametre n° {{ i+1 }}</h2>
                <label>label</label>
                <input class="form-control" ngControl="label" type="text" value="{{ parametre?.Parameter?.label }}" />
                <label>description</label>
                <input class="form-control" ngControl="description" type="text" value="{{ parametre?.Parameter?.description }}" />
                <label>parameterType</label>
                <input class="form-control" ngControl="mandatory" type="text" value="{{ parametre?.Parameter?.parameterType }}" />
                <label>mandatory</label>
                <input class="form-control" ngControl="parameterType" type="text" value="{{ parametre?.Parameter?.mandatory }}" />
                <label>dataType</label>
                <input class="form-control" ngControl="dataType" type="text" value="{{ parametre?.Parameter?.dataType }}" />
                <label>dataType</label>
                <input class="form-control" ngControl="requestType" type="text" value="{{ parametre?.Parameter?.requestType }}" />
                <label>processParameterIdentifier</label>
                <input class="form-control" ngControl="processParameterIdentifier" type="text" value="{{ parametre?.Parameter?.identifier }}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I'm wrapping the Parameter ngControlGroup inside a blank ngControlGroup, then for hte formBuilder Array (parameters) and wrapping it inside an ngControlGroup too, and here is the Error that i'm Getting:

> EXCEPTION: Cannot find control 'parameters -> ' in [ in ]

Comment: Are you using the new RC.3 forms or the deprecated forms?

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer i'm using the deprecated ones ....

Comment: UP ..... still encountring the Problem